# Background image changes back to default after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui

Using React, I have it to where the user can go into their 'settings' page and click on an image that they want to be their background. Using DOM manipulation, it works! However, after refreshing the page (or returning to the site after closing the tab) the background goes back to the default image that I have in the CSS.

Can you write something that changes the background image url permanently?

Here's my BackgroundCard.js component:

```
  export default function BackgroundCard(props) {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");

  function setBackground() {
    body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${props.image})`;
  }

  return (
    <Card style={{ maxWidth: 275, marginTop: 10 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          height="300"
          component="img"
          image={props.image}
          title={props.title2}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.title}
          </Typography>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Button
              id="bgImg"
              variant="contained"
              style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              onClick={setBackground}
            >
              Select
            </Button>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to use `localStorage` to persist anything on refresh

Comment: You need to use _something_ to persist their choice, `localStorage` is _one_ of many choices. If you have a back-end where users have accounts of some kind, and you already have a login, then saving their choice on the back-end as a preference is superior to localstorage because it will remain for any browser on any computer; localStorage is not shared by browsers. If I use both Chrome and Firefox, my choice made in Firefox and saved in localStorage would "disappear" when I switched to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save his choice into **localStorage** or **cookies** or better to his profile into database but I don't know if you use some.

Here is an example with **localStorage**

```js
export default function BackgroundCard(props) {
  var body = document.getElementById("body");

  function setBackground() {
    localStorage.setItem('bg', props.image);  // Set into local storage
    body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${props.image})`;
  }

  return (
    <Card style={{ maxWidth: 275, marginTop: 10 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          height="300"
          component="img"
          image={props.image}
          title={props.title2}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {props.title}
          </Typography>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Button
              id="bgImg"
              variant="contained"
              style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              onClick={setBackground}
            >
              Select
            </Button>
          </div>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

And than somewhere in your **App.jsx** you can add

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const img = localStorage.getItem('bg');
   if (img) {
      body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${img})`;
   }
}, []);
```

Not sure how your **App.jsx** looks

You can add this even into your index.js or any top code

Comment: That worked when refreshing, but when exiting and then re-entering the page it went back to default. I'm using Firebase to store data of users - you mentioned it's better if I did this through a database. How would I go from there?

Comment: @spidamitchell This makes no sense for me (if you stay in same browser) becasuse "data stored in localStorage has no expiration time" see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @spidamitchell I am not skilled with firebase sorry, but just add new attribute to your user with bg value and when you load user data into react from firebase you can check if that attribute is set and use it as background (this is just logic)